# How *Auto* Are Pentax Auto Extension Tubes?

Tags: pentax, extension-tubes

While asking for extension tubes for a Pentax DSLR, Pentax replied:

> As requested, please find the following extension tubes available.
>   Product 30535, auto extension tube set B Product 30551, life-size auto
>   extension tube B 50mm w/case Product 30556, life-size auto extension
>   tube B 100mm w/case

After searching for these products online I found different information regarding them. One  forum post somewhere said the only auto part is that the meter at the *widest* aperture and stop down to the *smallest*. Is this true?

My intuition is that extension tubes stop down to whatever aperture is set in the camera. Perhaps they would be able to autofocus too but I do not care about that :) Only that there is still control over aperture without a lens with an aperture ring.

**Does anyone know how the automatic aperture and metering work with these tubes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the Pentax-brand tubes rely on an aperture set on the lens, so while they'll work with manual-focus K-mount lenses and most of the FA-series, they won't let you work properly with the D-series lenses that don't have an aperture ring. They *are* "auto" in the sense that they allow you to focus and meter wide-open, then stop the lens down to the set aperture mechanically, but they don't appear to have the contacts necessary for electronic aperture control. (The newer digital-intent lenses are essentially stopped-down to minimum aperture mechanically all of the time, as you would have to do with a lens having an aperture ring if you wanted to use the aperture setting on the camera body.)

Kenko used to make a proper set of automatic tubes for the Pentax that gave full electronic aperture control and screw-drive autofocus, but while they still show up on the used market from time to time, they appear to have been discontinued. There are, of course, any number of off-brand (Chinese) tubes out there claiming to be auto, but they tend not to give away too many secrets in their ads and placements, and I'd suspect they're just K-mount mechanical linkages since I can't see anything that looks like electrical contacts in any of the pictures.